# Korea Working Vacation Jobs

Tags: working-visas, south-korea

I am a US permanent resident and am looking into doing a working vacation. From what I can tell in some countries, such as Australia, there are many different organizations that can help you find a job after arrival. This does not seem to be the case for Korea. I was wondering if there were any organizations that I should look into, or where I would be able to look for work when I arrive.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of employment agencies in South Korea. However, I haven't seen any that specialize in expats.

Here are some resources off Google:

- http://www.jobpostingkorea.com/
- http://www.learn4good.com/jobs/language/english/list/country/south_korea/

That being said, it really depends on several factors:

- Where will you be? Seoul or elsewhere?
- How long will you be there for?
- What kinds of jobs are you looking for?
- What are your qualifications?
- What will your visa status be?

In my case, I went to Seoul for 8 months and my goal was to get hired as an English tutor. All it took me was a few minutes of Googling to find some numbers to call. Mind you, this was 8 years ago.